# How do I fix the - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyngrok' error code that comes up in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion, pyngrok

I'm trying to run stable diffusion in google colab. I got it to work for a moment before being disconnected and then when I try to run it again it comes up with this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEtNj.png)

I don't know anything about coding, just want to have some fun ;(

I've tried looking it up, but I can't find anything specific to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package. [From the docs](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#google-colaboratory), here how you would do that in Google Colab:

```
!pip install pyngrok
```

Comment: really appreciate the help. i did that then it comes up with NameError: name 'os' is not defined. Do I have to activate everything again if it disconnects the run time?

Comment: I haven't used Colab in a while, but yes, I believe you would have to restart / activate everything again if you disconnect the runtime. `os` is a system-defined module, so if it's "missing", then Python hasn't been initialized.